# Calendar UsageLimits Error with Low Request Volume for Shared Calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api

We're encountering a perplexing issue related to the Google Calendar API's "UsageLimits" error, and we'd appreciate some insight into this peculiar situation.

In our setup, we have multiple endpoints that interact with the Google API on behalf of various organizations. Each user initiates their calls using their own access token, and we track these requests in our database.

Here's the crux of the issue: despite our request volume rarely exceeding 200 requests per minute for the entire organization, we're consistently running into the "UsageLimits" error:

```
{'error': {'errors': [{'domain': 'usageLimits', 'reason': 'quotaExceeded', 'message': 'Calendar usage limits exceeded.'}], 'code': 403, 'message': 'Calendar usage limits exceeded.'}}
```

when making POST requests to the following endpoint:

`POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{calendar_id}/events`

Notably, if the `calendar_id` refers to a shared calendar, we consistently receive a 403 response. However, if the calendar_id corresponds to a **personal** calendar, we consistently receive a 200 response for the same POST request.

In contrast, GET requests:

`GET  https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{calendar_id}/events` to the shared calendar always return 200.

We're  wondering if the "UsageLimits" error might be related to this specific shared calendar(on creation via POST or if it should be entirely unrelated, given that Google typically enforces these limits on a per-user basis.

We're actively seeking insights into what might be causing this discrepancy and how to address it. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!